# Is there any way to get an ExtJS GridPanel to automatically resize its width, but still be contained inside some non-ExtJS-generated HTML?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to include an ExtJS `GridPanel` inside a larger layout, which in turn must be rendered inside a particular div in some pre-existing HTML that I don't control.

From my experiments, it appears that the `GridPanel` only resizes itself correctly if it's within a `Viewport`. For instance, with this code the `GridPanel` automatically resizes:

```
new Ext.Viewport(
    {
        layout: 'anchor',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'foo',
                layout: 'fit', items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'grid',
                        // define the grid here...
```

but if I replace the first three lines with the lines below, it doesn't:

```
new Ext.Panel(
    {
        layout: 'anchor',
        renderTo: 'RenderUntoThisDiv',
```

The trouble is, `Viewport` always renders directly to the body of the HTML document, and I need to render within a particular div.

If there is a way to get the `GridPanel` to resize itself correctly, despite not being contained in a `ViewPort`, that would be ideal.  If not, if I could get the `Viewport` to render the elements within the div, I'd be fine with that.  All of my ExtJS objects can be contained within the same div.

Does anybody know of a way to get a GridPanel to resize itself correctly, but still be contained inside some non-ExtJS-generated HTML?

Comment: I feel your pain. I had to use ExtJs for a whole year and found it to be, to put it nicely, less than flexible. What it did it did wonderfully, but if you ever had to change any default behavior it was a lot of work. Good luck.

Comment: Does the div have a fixed width (e.g. 600px)? Or the layout of the site is liquid (elastic)?

Comment: The div does not have a fixed width.  The div is supposed to be width of the whole window.  (The other HTML puts things above and below it.)  If the div was fixed width, I wouldn't have even noticed this problem.

I note that other ExtJS components resize themselves fine, including the panel that contains the grid.

Comment: @Robusto, hear that! I spent a whole day trying to set a default value to a combo box :( mental

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To resize Ext JS components when they are not in a `Viewport`, you need to pass along browser window resize events.

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(panel.doLayout, panel);
```

In your example, store the `Panel` into `var panel`, and then set up the event handler after the var declaration but still inside of `Ext.onReady`.

Here is a full single page solution:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-3.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script>
      Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext-3.1.1/resources/images/default/s.gif';
      Ext.onReady(function(){
        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
          renderTo: 'areaDiv',
          layout: 'fit',
          items: [{
            height: 200,
            title: 'foo',
            xtype: 'grid',
            cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
              {header: "id", width: 400},
              {header: "name", width: 400}
            ]),
            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
              fields: ['id','name'],
              data: [[1,'Alice'],[2,'Bill'],[3,'Carly']]
            })
          }]
        });
        //pass along browser window resize events to the panel
        Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(panel.doLayout, panel);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    header
    <div id="areaDiv" style="padding:30px;"></div>
    footer
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that I've removed the redundant panel (a `GridPanel` *is* a `Panel`, so no need to wrap it), and used layout `fit` instead of `anchor`. Layout `fit` is actually the key to a fluid layout. Make the browser smaller, then bigger. You'll see the grid always fills the entire width, with the exception of the padding.

Comment: Thank you!  One thing I'll note, in case anyone reading this runs into the same thing: in my actual application, I did need the "redundant" container around the grid to make it work.  The panel that renders to the div (analogous to the "foo" panel in my example) had more than one item in it, but the grid still didn't resize unless it was in a `fit` layout, which can only have one item in it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to "comment anywhere" yet, but I do have a fix to the "not working when window is resized smaller" problem described by HOCA.  I was having the same problem too, using the solution outlined by this answer.  After Googling around for a while, I found [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?61716-Panel-resize-issue-in-IE/page2) on the sencha.com website.  Using a similar technique to the one described there seems to work better cross-browser (using the exact solution offered there seems to work somewhat differently between FF/IE).

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function() {
    // pass "true" to get the contendWidth (excluding border/padding/etc.)
    mainPanel.setWidth(Ext.getBody().getWidth(true));
    // seems to be no need to call mainPanel.doLayout() here in my situation
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In IE6 and Chrome your solution doesn't seem to work when the browser window is resized/made smaller that the original size.  It does, however, resize properly when the browser window is resized larger.  Does the `Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(panel.doLayout, panel)` not fire when the browser window is made smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the layout: 'fit' to the panel that contains the grid

```
var myGridTab = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'border',
    region: 'center',
    autoScroll: true,
    animCollapse: false,
    forceFit: true,
    title: ' My Grid Tab ',
    split: true,
    border: false,
    items: [
    {
        region: 'center',
        **layout: 'fit',**
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [myGrid],
        height: 150,
        forceFit: true
    }]
});
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)