# Extjs table/grid auto expand to full

Tags: extjs

How do I go about making the gridpanel/table in extjs auto expand based on the window size?
Thanks
I added layout :'fit'.. i didn't change much

```
var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: mystore,
    multiSelect: true,
title:'Notifications for ' + jsonServiceId + ' <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No images to display'
    },
    //reserveScrollOffset: true,
renderTo: containerEl,
         layout:'fit',

    columns: [{
        text: 'Sell',
        flex: 10,
        dataIndex: 'Sell',
       renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
       //  alert(record.get('Sell'));


  }
    },{
        text: 'Class',
        flex: 10,
        dataIndex: 'ClassName'
    },


  {
        text: 'Last Changed',
        flex: 20,
        dataIndex: 'LastChangedAt',
  xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'd-M-Y h:i a'
    }
]     
});
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366211/is-there-any-way-to-get-an-extjs-gridpanel-to-automatically-resize-its-width-bu

Answer (score 0):

It's a layout thing. You should add layout: 'fit' to the parent container. It will make your grid expand to the size of parent container.

Just as here in example:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html