# extjs 3.4 column not fully expanding when window is maximised

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating an EXT application that uses several `Panel` components. One of them is a `GridPanel` containing a single `Column`. In my `GridPanel` I have set the `autoExpandColumn` config to this `Column` because one of my `Panel` components is collapsible, so when it is collapsed the other `Panel` components expand and the `Column` also expands. When the `Window` is at its normal size and the collapsible `Panel` is collapsed, the `Column` does expand to take up the full width of the `GridPanel`. However, when the `Window` is maximised, the column does not expand, but stays at the same width that it was when the window was maximised and the collapsible `Panel` was not collapsed (this is bigger than when the `Window` is at its normal size). The `Window` has a `BorderLayout` which is why the first two `Panel` components use the `region` property.

Here is the relevant code:

config for the `Window`:

```
                title: 'Engineering Works',
                width: 915,
                height: 550,
//                minHeight: 550,
//                minWidth: 915,
                resizable: false,
                padding: 10,
                shim:false,
//                monitorResize: true,
                confirmClose: true,
                animCollapse:false,
                constrainHeader:true,
                style: {
                    margin: "10px"
                },
                layout: "border",
                items: [filterFormPanel,centrePanel]
```

Collapsible panel:

```
var filterFormPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    region: "west",
    monitorResize:true,
    width: "38%",
    title: "Filter",
    collapsible: true,
    id: windowId + "filter",
    items: [stationsPanel, datesPanel, daysPanel, impactPanel, searchButton]
});
```

centrePanel (contains two other panels, the first of which (searchResultsPanel) is the `GridPanel` explained above

```
   var centrePanel = new Ext.Panel({
        region: "center",
        layout:'border',
        monitorResize:true,
        items: [searchResultsPanel,individualResultPanel]
    });
```

searchResultsPanel (contains a `rowclick` listener which I've omitted because it's very long and not relevant to this problem):

```
    var searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        title: "All Results",
        id: windowId + "allresults",
        border: false,
        monitorResize:true,
        autoScroll: true,
        region:'center',
        forceFit: true,
        colModel:  myColumnModel,
        autoExpandColumn: windowId + "summarycolumn",
        store: mystore
    });
```

It's worth pointing out that the `GridPanel` itself does expand properly at all times, it's just the `Column` inside it does not take the full width of the `GridPanel` when the `Window` is maximised and the `filterFormPanel` is collapsed.

I have tried, without success:

1. Putting the searchResultsPanel inside its own parent Panel and giving it a layout of fit, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104227/extjs-table-grid-auto-expand-to-full) question (and some others). In any case I realised this is probably moot because this concerns the GridPanel not expanding, a problem which I do not have.
2. Setting the `width` config of the `Column` to be equal to the width of the `GridPanel` when the collapsible `Panel` is collapsed and expanded. This did not solve my problem and caused the `Panel` components on the right (inside `centrePanel`) to have horizontal scroll bars when the collapsed `Panel` was expanded.

Comment: I remember back in 3.4 days, ExtJS has many issues with updating the layout automatically. Perhaps you could find a solution by forcing the GridView (in side the Panel) to re-layout. I hope this helps

Comment: I'm not using a GridView component unfortunately.

Comment: GridView in the View component in the GridPanel. This "View" is automatically created for you by the GridPanel

Comment: How can I configure this View if I'm not explicitly declaring it?

Comment: Try gridPanel.getView().refresh()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing the `autoExpandColumn` config in my `GridPanel` and surrounding the `forceFit` config with `viewConfig` because it's a config of the GridView component. So my GridPanel now looks like this (minus the listeners):

```
var searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title: "All Results",
    id: windowId + "allresults",
    border: false,
    monitorResize:true,
    autoScroll: true,
    region:'center',
    colModel:  myColumnModel,
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    store: mystore
});
```